# How can I count a query from squeryl

Tags: scala, squeryl

I have a method which return a Query:

```
def list:Query[User] = from(users)(u => where(u.age>20) select(u))
```

Now I want to count the list, but this method:

```
list.count(_ => true)
```

will get and loop all elements in the list.

I want to find a solution to make a "select count" statement from the `Query[User]`, but not found yet.

Or I have to write another method for count:

```
def countList: Long = from(users)(u => where(u.age>20) compute(count))
```

Which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to compose the two queries:

```
from(list)(_ => compute(count))
```

Comment: It can't be compiled: `missing arguments for method from in trait FromSignatures;
follow this method with _ if you want to treat it as a partially applied function`

Comment: You would query the `Queryable` the same as a `Table`, so the syntax above looks more illustrative. The compilable code would probably look like: `from(list)(l => compute(count))`

Answer (score 0):

In such cases it might make sense to make a common query builder, so you can keep the condition logic at a single place. It's handy when you are paging a query result set.

```
def queryBuilder[T](action: User => WhereState[Conditioned] => QueryYield[T]) : Query[T] = from(users)(u => action(u)(where(u.age>20)))

def countQuery = queryBuilder(u => w => w.compute(count))

def selectQuery = queryBuilder(u => w => w.select(u))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of DAO object:

```
def countByJobPostingId(jobPostingId: Int): Long = {
  inTransaction {
    val q = from(table)(t =>
      where(t.jobPostingId === jobPostingId)
        compute count
    )

    LOG.debug(q.statement)

    q.head.measures
  }
}
```